# How to overwrite css files modified in PurgeCSS CLI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using PurgeCSS CLI to delete unused css classes in my React project.
I'm using this command: `purgecss --css src/**/*.css --content src/**/*.js`, what is doing is scanning all the js files in /src, detecting unused classes in css files and returning them to me in the console. PurgeCSS contains an --output flag to write files changed in an specific directory, is there any way to rewrite css files in each folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the programmatic API to do so.

This code sets the purgecss's content to all the built HTML and JS files. Then processes each file and overwrites the file.

./scripts/purgecss.mjs

```js
import { readFile, writeFile, stat } from "fs/promises"
import glob from "fast-glob"
import purgecss from "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss"
import postcss from "postcss"

const sourceFiles = await glob(["./dist/**/*.html", "./dist/**/*.js"], {
  dot: true,
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  onlyFiles: true,
  absolute: true,
})

const cssFiles = await glob(["./dist/**/*.css"], {
  dot: true,
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  onlyFiles: true,
  absolute: true,
})

const postcssProcessor = postcss([
  purgecss({
    content: sourceFiles,
  }),
])

await Promise.all([
  ...cssFiles.map(async (cssFile) => {
    const cssString = await readFile(cssFile, "utf8")
    const { css, map } = await postcssProcessor.process(cssString, { from: cssFile, to: cssFile, map: true })
    await writeFile(cssFile, css)
    if (map !== undefined) {
      await writeFile(cssFile.replace(/\.css$/, ".css.map"), map.toString())
    }
    console.log(`${cssFile}: ${(await stat(cssFile)).size / 1024} KB`)
  }),
])
```

```
npm run build && node ./scripts/purgecss.mjs
```

You will need to have `fast-glob` and `postcss` installed.

Comment: This answer does not use OPs paths, also I did not manage to get it working. More explanation would be appreciated since OP (and me) are clearly using the purgecss CLI and not the programmatic API. 
Anyway how is this not an option in the CLI? This is one of the most basic use cases for static sites. I am also assuming OP wants to purge a static site.

Comment: The CLI doesn't have it for some reason. Maybe, I can make a PR and add it. I took this from my project, which is working there. You might want to provide more information about the issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that uses the Purgecss programmatic API directly.

This code sets the purgecss's content to all the built HTML and JS files. Then processes each file and overwrites the file.

./scripts/purgecss.mjs

```js
import { writeFile, stat } from "fs/promises"
import { PurgeCSS } from "purgecss"


const purgeCSSResult = await new PurgeCSS().purge({
  content: ["./dist/**/*.js", "./dist/**/*.html"],
  css: ["./dist/**/*.css"],
})

await Promise.all([
  ...purgeCSSResult.map(async ({ css, file }) => {
    const initialSize = (await stat(file)).size / 1024

    await writeFile(file, css)

    const postSize = (await stat(file)).size / 1024
    console.log(`${file}: ${initialSize} -> ${postSize} KB`)
  }),
])
```

```
npm run build && node ./scripts/purgecss.mjs
```